# Where I have several parameters for a function, how do I pass a single list containing all of the arguments in exact order in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, list, parameters, arguments

I have a function which contains several parameters, as usual, like so:

```
Function MyFunction(ByRef Param1 As String, ByRef Param2 As String, ByRef Param3 As String)
    ' some code
End Function
```

I want to be able to pass a list, containing all of the parameters in question, to the function.

```
Dim MyList As New List(Of String) From {"I am a string", "I am also a string", "Again, a string"}
```

Is there any inbuilt routine, or some other method I could do myself, which would allow me to, assuming I have these arguments in exactly the same order as the parameters for `MyFunction`, pass this list as it stands into `MyFunction`?

Comment: *Please don't pass a list*... pass an object/class containing what you need...less errors and easier to maintain.

Comment: That doesn't really help my problem still. Happy to change data structure if it makes the program more efficient.

Comment: why wouldn't it, you pass one object, then pull what ever you want out of it...

Comment: But I want to pass one argument that effectively covers all three parameters. Not pull out individually the three arguments contained in the object to satisfy the individual parameters.

Comment: then change your signature... you can't pass one argument that fulfills all three seperate ones. Another option, create another routine that takes only one parameter and then call the other and pass what you need to ... Also, they don't need to be `ByRef`.

Comment: I guess you want something generic, which you could use for different methods. You'd probably need Reflection, but you won't be able to call the method `MyFunction` and pass a different number of arguments without creating an overloaded `MyFunction`, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: I note that `MyFunction("I am a string", "I am also a string", "Again, a string")` is actually *less* coding than `Dim MyList As New List(Of String) From {"I am a string", "I am also a string", "Again, a string"} ... MyFunction(MyList)`

Comment: Do the parameters need to be `ByRef`?

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible. There are ways to change the method you have to be able to call it in different ways but, as it stands, you need to pass three arguments to your method. Why would you want to do it otherwise to begin with? If you explain what you're trying to achieve, rather than how you're trying to achieve it, we may be able to provide a proper solution. The fact that your example shows a function with no return type and three `ByRef` parameters indicates that you're trying to write garbage code, so I'd suggest avoiding that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reflection to get close to your desired result. If you use a Module to define this helper function,

```vb
Public Module MyModule

    Function callByName(Of T)(name As String, args As IEnumerable(Of T)) As T
        Dim type = GetType(MyModule)
        Dim mi = type.GetMethod(name)
        Return CType(mi.Invoke(Nothing, args.Select(Function(o) DirectCast(o, Object)).ToArray()), T)
    End Function

    Function callByName(Of T)(instance As Object, name As String, args As IEnumerable(Of T)) As T
        Dim type = instance.GetType()
        Dim mi = type.GetMethod(name)
        Return CType(mi.Invoke(instance, args.Select(Function(o) DirectCast(o, Object)).ToArray()), T)
    End Function

End Module
```

Now there are some unknowns here. I don't know how your function `MyFunction` is declared. What is its return type? Is it an instance member of some class, or is it in a module? Assuming it's in the same module I put above, `MyModule`, put it there.

```vb
Public Function MyFunction(ByRef Param1 As String, ByRef Param2 As String, ByRef Param3 As String) As String
    Return Param1 & Param2 & Param3 & "Static"
End Function
```

It could also be an instance member of the calling class. So put it in there

```vb
Public Function MyFunction(ByRef Param1 As String, ByRef Param2 As String, ByRef Param3 As String) As String
    Return Param1 & Param2 & Param3 & "Instance"
End Function
```

(right, they are identical except for what they return)

So calling them is easy. It's simply like this

```vb
Dim args = {"a", "b", "c"}
Dim resultStatic = callByName("MyFunction", args)
Dim resultInstance = callByName(Me, "MyFunction", args)
```

> resultStatic = "abcStatic"
>   resultInstance = "abcInstance"

See? You are passing the name of a function as a string, and the args. This will only work when the args are all the same type, and the return type of the function is the same. You could also change the generics around. But again, I don't know the return type of your function.

You could also make it work we a `Sub` I suppose. Just play around with the Reflection stuff in `callByName`.

No, there is no built in way to call a multi-parameter function by passing in one argument, unless they are all optional. Hey, that's an option too, but it would require you to overload your `MyFunction`, and again it would defeat the purpose.

If you don't like using a string to call a method, you could also use `NameOf`

```vb
Dim resultStatic = callByName(NameOf(MyModule.MyFunction), args)
```

This answer will require zero rewrite of your existing functions. I assume this is what you seek.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that represents the data you want to pass:

```
Class X
  Public Property Param1 as String
  Public Property Param2 as String
  Public Property Param3 as String
End Class
```

Create an overload of your function that accepts this argument:

```
Function MyFunction(p as X)
    Console.WriteLine("P1 is " + x.Param1)
    Console.WriteLine("P2 is " + x.Param2)
    Console.WriteLine("P3 is " + x.Param3)
    Return ...
End Function
```

You can still have your 3 parameter version if you want, just have the overload call it instead:

```
Function MyFunction(p as X)
    Return MyFunction(x.Param1, x.Param2, x.Param3)
End Function

Function MyFunction(param1 As String, param2 As String, param3 As String)
    Console.WriteLine("P1 is " + x.Param1)
    Console.WriteLine("P2 is " + x.Param2)
    Console.WriteLine("P3 is " + x.Param3)
    Return ...
End Function
```

If your arguments are all the same type, you could think about writing a function that takes a paramarry:

```
Function MyFunction(ParamArray p() as String)
    Console.WriteLine("P1 is " + p(0))
    Console.WriteLine("P2 is " + p(1))
    Console.WriteLine("P3 is " + p(2))
    Return ...
End Function
```

That can be called either with split out values or with a collection:

```
MyFunction("This", "for", "example")

Dim s() as String = {"This", "for", "example"}
MyFunction(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overload your function with 2 different types of parameters. The first passes the individual elements of the list and the second passes the list as a whole and addresses the elements inside the function.

```
Dim MyList As New List(Of String) From {"I am a string", "I am also a string", "Again, a string"}

Private Overloads Function MyFunction(ByRef Param1 As String, ByRef Param2 As String, ByRef Param3 As String) As String
    Return Param1 & Param2 & Param3
End Function

Private Overloads Function MyFunction(lst As List(Of String)) As String
    Dim Param1 = lst(0)
    Dim Param2 = lst(1)
    Dim Param3 = lst(3)
    Return Param1 & Param2 & Param3
End Function

Private Sub CallFunctions()
    MyFunction(MyList(0), MyList(1), MyList(2))
    'Or
    MyFunction(MyList)
End Sub
```